# Function to know that a variable is string or number on foxpro

Tags: string, numbers, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am having a difficult time telling that a variable is string or number on foxpro 6 or other version. I am new in this languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the VARTYPE or TYPE functions - these are slightly different and you should review the documentation before deciding which to use.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Vartype() function - it will return 'N' for numeric, 'C' for character and so on.